# How to compute F1-score when there are NA in the vectors?

Tags: missing-data, f1

I am using the f1-score (f1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall) to compute the similarity between two vectors (let's call them actual and pred). There are nevertheless some missing values in these vectors:

```
actual = [-1,1,'NA',1,1,1,1,0,1,-1]
pred   = ['NA',1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,'NA',-1]
```

As simple as it can get, I am using the f1 formula:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score:
f1= f1_score(actual,pred,average='micro')
```

What is the correct way to deal with these `NA` values? I thought about using listwise correction to remove the row comparisons when `NA` appears but I am certainly losing some information.

Comment: perhpas the answer to your question is related to the answer of this question. Why your variables have `NaN` (not a number) values?

Comment: Well, I am using f1 to compare two vectors that I have created arbitrarily to compare outputs from scientific papers. Hence, they do not come from a classification exercise characteristics of machine learning

Comment: my previous question stated differently:  By `NaN` do you really mean `NA` ?

Comment: Yes, I meant missing values indeed, tks for the clarification

Comment: Hoping the missing values are at random you can consider listwise deletion, otherwise you cannot do much with it.

Comment: Otherwise, if you have enought data and the missingness is reasonably random, you might consider imputing the missing values by some multiple imputations procedure s.t. as using estimated conditional relative frequencies form the complete observations. If you are interested on this, let me know and I can provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have proceed by applying listwise deletion indeed. Yet, the values come from an evaluation of the inputs appearing and not appearing in literature reviews so its randomization is relative. If you can guide me on the estimation of the conditional relative frequencies i would be happy. Always another resource to have at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `actual` and `pred` can both take values in $\{-1,0,1\}$, one way impute the missing values is as follows.

First, remove all the observations with at least one missing value; let's call this the filtered dataset. Estimate the joint frequency distribution of `actual` and `pred` variables, i.e. get the two-way table of joint relative frequencies using the filtered dataset.

Suppose the estimated two-way table is

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|c} 
& & \text{pred}\\
\text{actual}  & -1 & 0  & 1 & Total\\ \hline
-1 & f_{11} & f_{12} & f_{13} &f_{1\bullet} \\ 
0 & f_{21} & f_{22} & f_{23} &f_{2\bullet}  \\
1 & f_{31} & f_{32} & f_{33} &f_{3\bullet}  \\\hline
 & f_{\bullet1} & f_{\bullet2} & f_{\bullet3} &f_{\bullet\bullet}=1  \\
\end{array}$$

Now let's assume that we have an observation with missing `pred` and `actual` taking value $-1$. Compute the normalised frequencies
$$\tilde{f}_{11} = f_{12}/f_{1\bullet},\,\,\tilde{f}_{12} = f_{12}/f_{2\bullet},\,\,\tilde{f}_{13}=f_{13}/f_{3\bullet};$$
note that $\tilde f_{12}+\tilde f_{12}+\tilde f_{13}=1.$

Impute a value for `pred` by drawing randomly from $\{-1,0,1\}$ with cell probabilities $(\tilde f_{12},\tilde f_{12},\tilde f_{13}).$

Clearly, there must be some independence between `actual` and `pred` for this approach to be useful. If there is no dependence between these variables you can sample directly from the relative marginal frequency distribution.

Comment: Thanks @utobi, smart way to overcome the issue!